# How to convert a file in alias in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, alias

I am writing an application that backs up files and helps to restore them.

However, when I am backing up an Alias file (not a symlink), its restore gives indeed the same file contents, but is not seen as an alias by the system (chmod gives rw-r--r--@ for an alias and only rw-r--r-- without @ for the file).

How can I convert the file in alias ?

Edit: After having read about the @ in chmod, it seems that the alias information are stored in the extended attributes. Hence my question: How to read and store extended attributes in a file in Cocoa ?